# selecting listview 's ITEMS with mouse click and key board UP and DOWN VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a selecting code in SUB ListView1_MouseClick working well with mouse ,but I want to select ITEMS with mouse and Key board up/down , when I  use  SUB Listview1_KeyDown  I couldn't selecting with mouse left click , how can I make my code in sub handle keyboard and mouse together ?

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseClick

        Dim sname As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        Label1.Text = sname

    End Sub
```

Comment: Ignore trying to make this work in code. Basic Windows functionality already has this covered. Use the CTRL key to keep the selection while navigating the list with arrow keys, and then mark it as selected with the Space Bar

Comment: CTRL + up/ down keys doesn't make any selection  with mouse_click SUB code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use other events like [ItemSelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) or [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Using the MouseClick is a bit to specific to mouse click, especially since you are looking for changes in SelectedItems.